# Placement of prepositional phrases

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I am very curious if it is correct to say:

"I got a lot of friends on this website".(or maybe the right one is "On this website I got a lot of friends"?)

Thank you in advance for your answer.

Comment: Make sure you distinguish between *I got*, which means *I obtained*, and *I have got*, which usually means *I have*.

Answer (score 3):

"Got" is fine, but it's "*I've* (I have) got a lot of friends on this site." The only preposition in the example is "on", which is totally correct and sounds natural.

It's also perfectly fine to drop the "got" entirely. "I have a lot of friends on this site."

Since "I've got" is decidedly informal (but extremely common), I checked with [*Grammar Girl*](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/is-have-got-acceptable-english) to be sure that it is, in fact, correct. She grudgingly agrees that it is.

Comment: What about the OP’s second version? Is it correct and should be used with coma as introductory elements?

Comment: The second example is not worded in a way that that's typical, but it would be fine to say, "On this website, I've got a lot of friends." I believe the comma is optional, it would be up to the author to decide if he needs a "speed-bump".

Comment: Since you brought up formality, I'll mention this: In writing, I'd recommend changing "a lot of" to "many" – _I have many friends on this site._